# Chef - need a light weight "queue" (for the life of the recipe)

Tags: queue, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chatops

Presently I have a chef recipe whereby I post messages to chat, inside a loop:

```
artifacts.each do |artifactItem|
    # Deploy the artifact
    #...

    # Post to chat
    chat_post "deployed artifact #{artifact_name}"
end
```

The result on my chat is like this:

```
chef [BOT]
deployed artifact A

chef [BOT]
deployed artifact B

chef [BOT]
deployed artifact C
```

I am wondering - is there an easy "queue" mechanism in chef, where I can queue up my deployment messages, and post them all at once (when my recipe completes) ? If so how would the code look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the delayed notifications system.

```
artifacts.each do |artifactItem|
    # Deploy the artifact
    #...

    # Post to chat
    r = chat_post "deployed artifact #{artifact_name}" do
      action :nothing
    end
    ruby_block "notification for #{artifact_name}" do
      block { }
      notifies :someaction, r
    end
end
```

Or something like that, make sure you check what action to use for the notification (whatever the default action on the `chat_post` resource is. Also this assumes `chat_post` is a resource and not some kind of helper method. If it's not a resource, you might need two `ruby_blocks`.

Comment: Thanks. The `chat_post` is actually under `chat/definitions/post.rb`... I guess it is a "helper method" (since we didnt completely understand how to implement it as a resource / provider / LWRP thing...). Though event based notifications seem like a better way to do it...

Comment: You'll have to port it over to a custom resource to do this, but that should hopefully be pretty easy :)

Comment: Ok, thanks @coderanger. I asked another question about specifically that, maybe you can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488843/chef-how-to-write-a-custom-resource-containing-dsl-for-execute

Answer (score 0):

You can use `node.run_state` to save transient data that is accessible for the current chef run.

Comment: True, but probably not a good idea here. Global state should be used only as a last resort and `run_state` in particular needs to be used very carefully as it's a shared global namespace.