# Chef - how to write a custom resource containing DSL for "execute"

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chatops

I have written a chef `definition` that posts to our chat server.

Since definitions are not recommended any more, how can I rewrite this as a resource? I'm particularly interested in how to use "event" ways to trigger the code.

File `chat\definitions\post.rb` :

```
define :chat_post do

  chat_url = 'https://chat.our.company/hooks/abcdef1234567890'
  message = params[:name]

  execute "echo" do
    command "curl -m 5 -i -X POST -d \"payload={"text": "#{message}"\" #{chat_url}"
    ignore_failure true
  end
end
```

Calling code in a recipe:

```
artifacts.each do |artifactItem|
  # deploy stuff
  # ...

  chat_post "#{node['hostname']}: Deployed #{artifact_name}-#{version}"
end
```

Now, I have read the chef documentation and tried various things (to be precise: a `Module`, a `library` and a `resource`) and read the documentation about [chef custom resources](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html), but without success.

Can someone please guide me: how to convert this code to a `resource`, if that is the proper way to do it (chef 12.6+) ?

I would appreciate to know

- where in the cookbook does a recipe resource go (`chat/recipes`, or some place else?)
- how the code should look (converting from my definition above)
- how is the new code called (from another recipe) and do I need any includes there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the custom_resource doc](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) something like this should do (untested):

in `chat/resources/message.rb`:

```
property :chat_url, String, default: 'https://chat.our.company/hooks/abcdef1234567890'
property :message, String, name_property: true

action :send
  execute "echo #{message}" do
    command "curl -m 5 -i -X POST -d \"payload={"text": "#{message}"\" #{chat_url}"
    ignore_failure true
  end
end
```

And now in another cookbook:

```
artifacts.each do |artifactItem|
  # prepare the message:

  chat_message "#{node['hostname']}: Deployed #{artifact_name}-#{version}" do
    action :nothing
  end

  # deploy stuff
  # dummy code follow
  deploy artifactItem['artifact_name'] do
    source "whatever_url/#{artifactItem}
    notifies :send,"chat_message[#{node['hostname']}: Deployed #{artifactItem["artifact_name"]}-#{artifactItem['artifact_name']}]"
  end
end
```

By default notifications are delayed, so the chat_message resource will fire only at end of run.

you deploy cookbook will have to `depends` on the `chat` cookbook to be able to call its custom_resource.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! the name_property thing was very neat. Any way I can buy you a beer? This helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped ;)

Comment: By the way if the resource only has one action, it seems you dont need to specity `:send` in the `notifies`

Comment: Yep, but I take as good practice to always specify the action. And this avoid breaking everything if you add a second action to the resource (let's say a send_SMS for example